# When text contains underscore XPath is unable to find element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am using Python and Selenium to create an automated backup system for folders. I ran into issues when the folder contained an under "_."

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pg-gal pv' and .//div[contains(., '" + folder_list[n] + "')]]")
```

For example, the folder I was trying to click on was named "Clinton_Elementary" and I kept getting an error. I tested the same script with other folders not containing the underscores and it worked perfectly as expected.

I am trying to select an element by class but I'm getting an error because the selection contains text that has an underscore in it.

```
Traceback Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='pg-gal pv' and .//div[contains(., 'Clinton_Elementary')]]"}
```

EDIT: The rest of the code in the project has no errors and when I try to select elements that do not have an underscore I do not have an issue here is a screenshot using XPath Helper for chrome. In the second image when the folder is highlighted which means the folder was successfully selected. Are there any other workarounds to select the element without modifying the string?

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCTew.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWURs.png)

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: @That1Guy I am trying to select the element by its class and text, but I am receiving an error. After testing out different methods I realized that it is developing an error because the text contains an underscore. I am not able to change the text for these elements so I am looking for a work around.

Comment: If you're getting an error you should edit your post to include the complete traceback.

Comment: Your problem isn't likely to actually be about XPath and underscores.  Post a full [mcve] or you're unlikely to get an answer that resolves your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element by its *classname* and *innerText* e.g. **Clinton_Elementary**, you can use the following solution:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pg-gal pv' and contains(., '" + folder_list[n] + "')]")
```

Comment: I am still receiving the same traceback error. I managed to get a temporary solution through an exception that splits folder_list into a smaller string.